# not exist weight property for widget in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying set value for weight property in eclipse mars and android 20
but it was not in properties window, and while get xml coding page it was not there. how to get weight property?

Comment: Are you trying to use weight on an element that is not a LinearLayout children? In case please share your layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

this is my layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="sajjad.sadeghi.test.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="Distance" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Volume" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Speed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Temprature" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="Design by android team "
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="2015"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_gravity` is a attribute of `LinearLayout`,so you can't use it in RelativeLayout.

Comment: but i don't use `android:layout_gravity` in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @sj.sadeghi,I didn't see `.LinearLayout` in your xml layout.

Comment: but in my eclipse `RelativeLayout` is default. Should i changed them?

Comment: you can change outest RelativeLayout to LinearLayout,or add LinearLayout to wrap your Buttons ,then you can use android:layout-weight.

Comment: thanks, i've got a problem. i want to change e.g `hint` of `textedit` from `properties` window but is not changed. i forced to change from `layout.xml` for first time.

Comment: I usually change from layout xml,I think it's a better way.